# Windows 2016 install in XenServer 7.1 asks for disk drivers

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-server-2016, xenserver

Fresh XenServer 7.1 installation, trying to install Windows 2016 Evaluation. Few seconds after pressing the *Install* button, I'm being asked for a *disk device driver* from Windows, which I don't know where to get.

[image: screenshot, in italian]

The VM is being created with the *Windows 2016 server* template, but I tried also with *Windows 10* and *Windows 2012R2* ones, same identical result.

Anyone knows where can I find those drivers, or if there's a working install procedure for Windows 2016 in XenServer?

Comment: odd... using the *en-US* version of the ISO instead of the *it-IT* went through! I'm installing! Still puzzled what's wrong with the Italian version...

Comment: You should post this as an answer for the next guy who runs into this!

Comment: I was letting space for a real answer before posting mine

Comment: Yours is a real answer. If someone comes along with a more detailed explanation, so be it; but yours is helpful and worth posting in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved myself, the culprit ended up being the **localized Italian installation ISO** of Windows 2016. Trying with the *en-US* version the installation went straight.